# Why does Chrome use more CPU when a large Knockout element is hidden?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, knockout.js

I have a single-page web app that uses Knockout.js 2.2.1 to display information streaming from a server (using socket.io, although I don't think that matters).  This app also contains a large data table, which is created from a JSON object using Knockout's `foreach` bindings.  (The table is big, but not enormous: 20 columns and 200 rows or so.)

Since the table is large, it can be opened/closed by the user by clicking buttons.  The data `<table>` is placed inside a `<div>` element that I can hide/show using jQuery's `.hide()` and `.show()` methods (which essentially work by setting and clearing CSS `display: none` on the `<div>`).

All of this functionality works.  However, I notice that after 'closing' (hiding) the big data table, Chrome's CPU usage jumps - all the way to 100% if the Knockout-generated table is big enough.  What's more interesting is that this *only* happens after the user has clicked somewhere inside the `<div>` element that contains the table when it is shown.  When the table is hidden (and CPU usage is high), clicking somewhere else on the page will return CPU usage back to normal.  The process will repeat at will.

Another possibly useful note: if I stop the streaming data from the server this problem doesn't happen (or, it's not noticeable in the CPU usage).  There is a single Knockout view model on this page, which manages both the streaming data from the server and the creation of this data table from a JSON object.  The two sets of data are otherwise completely separate - none of the changing data is displayed in the table, and the table contains no event bindings back to the view model.  It's as if the streaming data update of the Knockout model is causing work on the data table even though none of the streaming data is bound to the table.  *And* it does this only when the table is *not* displayed!

**Quick summary:**

- Web app uses Knockout to render a large data table when the page is loaded.
- This table is hidden with `.hide()` at startup in `$(document).ready`, but is displayed using `.show()`, after clicking a button, and can be hidden again
- If the mouse is clicked inside the data table, CPU usage in Chrome will jump to 100% after the table is hidden again.
- Clicking anything else on the page will bring the CPU usage back to normal.

**Other relevant information:**

- The Chrome JavaScript profiler shows the high CPU usage, but it's categorized simply as (program) time.
- Neither IE10 nor Firefox 20 on Windows show this problem.

Any ideas what's going on here, or suggestions for additional troubleshooting?

**jsFiddle:**

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/CTYMv/6/

Look at CPU usage after loading the fiddle, it should be low.  Click "Show Table", then click somewhere inside the div that pops up (gray background).  Then click "Hide Table" - CPU usage will increase significantly.  Then click anywhere else (white background), and CPU will return to normal.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Actually yes.  I thought it would be a little tough to simulate, but managed to get a pretty good example going.

Comment: Your issue may be caused by browser reflows? Have you checked that?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best way to check this is, but I'm open to suggestions if you have any.  It doesn't make sense to me that the simple act of clicking would affect browser reflows though - especially when my code isn't handling clicks in any way.

Comment: As a the simple workaround, you could detach element and reattach it when needed. Not sure it can work in your situation: http://jsfiddle.net/KQqjY/

Comment: @roasted - that actually seems to work for me.  Do you have any idea what's going on here?  I'm not sure of all the implications yet, but for now this does appear to be a good workaround.

Comment: I can't find the reason but I think it's related somehow to the "selected text". If you just click inside the table the cpu usage is smaller (50%) than if you actually select some text in it. Also if after selecting the text you don't click anywhere else, so the cpu keeps running on 100%, then you show the table again, the selection is remembered. If however you clicked somewhere else to drop the cpu usage, the selection is forgotten.

Comment: Also in the timeline of the debugger tool you can see that when the CPU load is high, much more "rendering" is happening than before-after. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Further to @peterfoldi's comment the layout time seems to be associated with a call to `ko.utils.setTextContent` when updating the streaming data (line 360 in knockout-2.2.1.debug.js) [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BCmxp.png). A typical stack trace when attaching a normal debugger during the high CPU is [screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5TJAn.png)

Comment: Reversing the order the tables appear in the markup also seems to improve things http://jsfiddle.net/CTYMv/10/

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, guys.  These are both good finds I hadn't tried yet, although I think I'm even more at a loss now than before!  The change in markup order is a big improvement in CPU, although I notice if I combine that with selecting text in the table (which makes it worse) it's clear that the problem still exists.

Comment: Also there is a VERY SMALL difference in the "GPU Process" CPU usage in Chrome Task Manager. It is smaller when the CPU load is high and then it goes up a little (10-20%) when the CPU load drops. It sounds not significant but happens on both PCs I tested it and happens consistently. I guess somehow GPU can't be used for rendering when the hidden element contains selected text?

Comment: RE: The question title it isn't really anything to do with knockout. A simpler repro is http://jsfiddle.net/CTYMv/17/ I would just assume a performance bug in Chrome

Comment: Following Martin's simplification in order to track down the core cause: also all the CSS can be removed.

Comment: And no need for the random numbers. http://jsfiddle.net/ghVs2/ I added the width and height in the CSS because the CPU usage depends on the size of the div: the bigger the size the higher the CPU load.

Comment: And without jquery http://jsfiddle.net/ghVs2/7/. In this case the random numbers are required to reproduce the issue. I assume otherwise it recognizes that nothing has changed.

Comment: Seems not a bug related to chrome but related to webkit engine as i can reproduce behaviour in Safari too. Unfortunately, i still don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Looking at chrome://tracing the layertreehostimpl:setvisible or GpuTransferBuggerMemory is responsible for the extra load.

Comment: @peterfoldi - Strange, I didn't see that method in the stacktrace at all when attaching a debugger and breaking when the CPU was busy http://i.stack.imgur.com/5TJAn.png

Comment: @MartinSmith I didn't go that far, but maybe you need to apply something from here for GPU related debugging? http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-gpu-related-code

Comment: @MartinSmith - I've seen some similar strange behavior in debugging, and with Chrome's profiling tools, in the application where I originally ran across this bug.  I can get Chrome to point to seemingly random functions throughout the code as the culprit simply by changing a line of unrelated code or reordering functions that should otherwise have no impact.  Also, I agree this in no way appears to be a problem with Knockout now - your test case without it is something I meant to try, but hadn't got to yet.

Answer (score 3):

I think we can now argue this is a bug in webkit engine. This bug only appears when using css property `display:none;`. Is it due to how GPU using webkit render hidden elements? Well, i still don't know...

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KQqjY/2/)

This is the simplest workaround i can think of, this should not interfered with any of your other code: {e.g knockout observable}

CSS:
{added pointer-events as suggested by Brandon}

```
.hidden{opacity:0;pointer-events:none} //don't use display:none here
```

JS:

```
//don't use hide/show jq methods as internally it set display none (fadeOut() methods too)
$('#btn_show').click(function(){
    $('#bigdatadiv').removeClass('hidden');
});
$('#btn_hide').on('click',function(){    
   $('#bigdatadiv').addClass('hidden')
});
```

I'm aware this is just a workaround and that still not answering your question: why this is happening?

Comment: you'd also want to add `pointer-events: none;` to the hidden css class.

Comment: Also...clearing the text selection when you set `display: none` on the div with `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()` seems to work also: http://jsfiddle.net/bman654/jjkf9/3/

Comment: @Brandon Ya, pointer-events:none could be added too. window.getSelection().removeAllRanges() is an other possible workaround.

Comment: Thanks for this concise write-up of a workaround.  Your previous jQuery detach() suggestion also worked in my case - do you have an opinion on which is preferable, or when each is appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for this thread; you would think the bug would have been fixed 2 years later.

window.getSelection().removeAllRanges() resolved things for me and was the simplest to fit into my code.

Answer (score -2):

Just use `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()`
before `.hide();` for a big blocks. Work fine for me.
It's stupid but it's true.